# Задержка перед запросом в retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

Добрый вечер, товарищи разработчики! Кто работал с retrofit?
Сейчас работаю с вк апи именно через retrofit. Но проблема в том, что пользователь может очень часто обновлять ленту, тем самым делать очень много запросов в секунду. Я использую асинхронные запросы. Как мне сделать задержку перед новым запросом?

Answer (score 0):

А в чем проблема? Насколько я знаю, ВКонтакте сам ограничивает частоту запросов, и при нарушении отсылает соответствующую ошибку, которую можно обрабатывать.
"Но проблема в том, что пользователь может очень часто обновлять ленту, тем самым делать очень много запросов в секунду."- обновлять ленту очень много раз в секунду? Что-то я такого не видел)
В крайнем случае, записывайте текущий timestamp куда-нибудь в SharedPreferences/статичную переменную и просто при новом запросе смотрите, чтобы разница между двумя датами (датой отправления и сохраненным timestamp) не была слишком большой

Comment: Да, но зачем говорить пользователю, что он слишком часто делает запросы? Может было бы логичнее заставить его подождать?